# How to create woocommerce products list

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to display all my products (around 1600 products currently) in a list/table with just Title,Description/Meta-Description,Price and Buy/Add to cart rows

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [this file](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/sample-products-loop/), find the file where your loop is defined, then create or copy over the template file for individual loop items to your theme folder. In the example from the link, this would be `content-product.php`, located inside the `/plugins/woocommerce/templates` folder. You can then fully customize the file to your needs.

You can also use the `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item` hook to add details to the loop item.